# What analysis can I do when I have different design and I would like to analyse together?

Tags: experiment-design, descriptive-statistics

I study the relationships between plant community (forest restoration) and soil properties.
My experiment is 15 years old, and I have a block design with five treatments and three replicates. I have also one reference area, a native forest that is located near this experiment. In both areas (experiment and native forest), I have the same plots size (50 x 50m). In these cases my amostral unity are the plots.

I would like to compare my experiment with the native forest, but I have different designs.
I would like to know how could I compare them.

Comment: What is "amostral unity"? I googled it but came up with nothing. Also, it might be helpful if you state what your variables are - what did you measure, and what is supposed to predict what?

Comment: In this case my amostral unity is my replicate. I have three replicates per treatment. For example, I would like to compare the organic carbon between treatments (treatments and native forest).

Comment: What I meant was, when I googled this: https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=amostral+unity&gws_rd=cr&ei=J16-VOC7O9Pi8AW_7ILwCw

I'm not familiar with the term amostral unity.

Comment: Okay, I understood. I don't know if "amostral unity" is correct in English language. I used a translation of português (Brazil) to English. But these words mean numbers of replicates. I wrote this because my replicate is my plot. In some studies your replicate can be a insect or a tree, but in my study my replicate is a plot. Do you understand?
I am sorry if I am not being clear. My english is not good.

Comment: No problem! I'm just trying to understand your question better. So, you have 16 plots total? 5 treatments x 3 plots of each + the 1 reference plot?

Comment: I hope that you had understood. In total I have 18 plots, because in the native forest I have also three plot with same size (50x50m).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense? And you have one measurement (for each variable) from each plot?

Comment: Yes, I have one measurement for each variable from each plot.

Comment: If you have the raw data, perhaps you can use just the last replicate, or take the average over the 3 replications. Then you would have a 6 group design without repeated measures. ALso, what do you mean by "amostral"?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so based on what you've told me, you have 18 measurements coming from 6 groups (5 treatment, 1 control) of 3 plots each. That sounds like you would use a one-way ANOVA to test to see if the means of the 6 groups are different. However, in this case, your sample size for each group would be 3, which is small, but fine, as long as you're not breaking any of the assumptions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Assumptions_of_ANOVA

Hopefully this is a good starting point, but I'm not an expert in your field and I don't know what's the convention there!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know yet if I can compare all treatments together since I have different designs. I don't have a true design in my forest native. She is my reference. Do you understand me?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean by "different designs"?

Comment: I have a block design with 5 treatments and 3 replicates, but my native forest is not part of this design. She is located near my design.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a statistical problem, more like a theoretical problem!